# Multiple multivariate time series forecasting with deep learning models like LSTM

Tags: python, deep-learning, time-series, lstm, forecasting

The picture below is a multiple multivariate time series forecasting problem. I want to forecast the value at certain time step of `C` based on values at previous time steps of `A, B, C`. For example, the inputs are values at `T0, T1, T2` of `A, B, C`, the output is the value at `T4` of `C`. Let say `N=100` so we have 100 samples, and 80 samples for training, 20 samples for testing. Within one sample I think it is a common multivariate LSTM time series forecasting problem with 3D input. But how to deal with such a multiple multivariate time series situation with 4D(?) input using LSTM or other suitable deep learing models? Are there any available tools/references? Thank you!

[image]